# How to consume rest api using android webview

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am building a hybrid android app (new in app development). In the main part of the app, i have a webview. The webview shows the html content/javascript/css.

I need to load content from my webservices and put it into my webview. How do i go about doing so?

My javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://www.hiss.ly/api/test.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){
         alert(result);
     },
     error: function(result){
        alert("Error");
     }
});
return false;
});

</script>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set the web view
    WebView webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//beware of XSS vulnerabiliUes
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because of cross domain issue. The below code solved it.

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since webview is client browser context, you can use native javascript [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object to consume your webservices, or for simplicity you can use [`jQuery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method enabling javascript in your webview configuration.

Comment: Hi, there is a problem because I am not loading my webview content from a http://... but from a file:// local

Comment: You need to enable `javascript` in your webview with webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true), and as you are loading your page from local, you should make reference to online jquery library [`loading online google  library service`](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Comment: hi @jansel, thanks for replying.. i tried your method, but still not working.. i updated the post with code, can you help me take a look?